# Wireframe clipping

Tags: interface

Recently I've been working on the anvil tutorial and noticed that my wireframe tends to do this. Is there any way to make it so it always appears above the mesh?[image]

Comment: Hello, if you're talking about the edges that are disappearing under the surfaces, it may be because of the Subdivision Surface effect, it changes the shape of your surfaces but the edges keep their position

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the circled option for the subsurface modifier, within the modifier stack:
[image]

This should pop the wireframe back into place

Comment: Leaving "Optimal Display" checked will still lead to some edges not being displayed; but I would leave it checked for performance reasons.